# Evaluated function as an object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am defining an object literal in JavaScript, but when I try to create a property that is a called function, I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: xxx is not defined` error.

Here's an example:

```
var person = {
    name : 'Saucy Jack',

    convenienceHook : this.getName('some predefined string'),

    getName : function(string) {
        console.log(this.name + string);
    }
};
```

This errors saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: convenienceHook is not defined`.

Nor does it work if I assign the property outside the object definition:

```
var person = {
    name : 'Saucy Jack',

    getName : function(string) {
        console.log(this.name + string);
    }
};

person.convenienceHook = person.getName('some predefined string');
person.convenienceHook(); //returns error
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In the first instance `getName()` isn't defined by the time you call it as the object instantiation isn't complete. In the second instance, `getName()` doesn't return anything (or returns `undefined`) which isn't a function.

Comment: That's not the error I'm getting (`TypeError: this.getName is not a function`)

Comment: what is convenienceHook supposed to be, a pointer to get name function with a parameter

Comment: getName doen't return anything ???  fubar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
var person = {
    name : 'Saucy Jack',

    convenienceHook : getname('some predefined string'),

    getName : function(string) {
        console.log(this.name + string);
    }
};
```

you’re calling a function called `getname` that doesn’t exist. `getName` is not a property on `person` yet, because `getname('some predefined string')` has to be evaluated before the object can exist, since it’s part of the object literal. Even if it did exist, though, you still wouldn’t be able to call it as a bare `getname`, and even if it did, you would have to capitalize `getName` properly.

Your second approach also just calls `person.getName`. It looks like you want to make another function that will call `getName`:

```
var person = {
    name : 'Saucy Jack',

    convenienceHook : function() {
        return this.getName('some predefined string');
    },

    getName : function(string) {
        console.log(this.name + string);
    }
};
```

Comment: your code doesn't match OP. `convenienceHook : this.getName` not `convenienceHook : getname`. And the reason this fails is not that `getName` isn't a property of `person` yet, it's that it isn't a property of `this` (global scope)

Comment: Sorry - I posted with a few typos. I edited the question. Are you saying there's not a way to have an evaluated function as a property inside an object literal definition if that function is a method of the object being created?

Comment: @GloryOfThe80s: `this` refers to the same thing inside an object literal as it does outside. It’s only inside *functions* that `this` can change. The explanation about `person` not existing still applies, anyway – `this` cannot ever refer to `person` at that point, because `person` has not been assigned a value and the value that will be assigned to it does not yet exist.

Comment: @GloryOfThe80s: Right, you can’t use a property of an object you’re creating before that object exists, i.e. while you’re creating it.

Comment: @minitech - I didn't see the "before" version (it's not in the edit history either, I guess it was quickly corrected)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var person = {
name: "Saucy Jack", 
convenienceHook: function() { return this.getName("Predefined text") },
getName: function(string) { 
    string=string||"";
    return this.name + string; } 
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn’t work. `person` doesn’t have a value when `person.getName` is evaluated.

Comment: That still won’t work and is more or less the same as the question itself.

Comment: @minitech In your answer, it works except if you put person.getName() it returns Saucy Jackundefined, my solution has no problem with that

Comment: Okay, seems to me that that’s not a problem though.

Comment: AND YES MY SOLUTION WORKS!! Remove wrong downvotes and mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

What you assigning is not a function, you need for example to return a function from the getName function, so the convenienceHook will be a function:

```
getName : function() {
    return function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first attempt fails is that `this` is not `person`, it's whatever `this` is in your current scope. could be global, or could be something else if that code is within a function.